# Programming PIC18F4520 stopwatch (MPLAB)

Tags: microchip, mplab, pic18

I'm making a code for PIC18F4520 stopwatch using a single 7 segment LED and 8 buttons. Button 1 to stop and button 2 to reset. The following is my code.

```
LIST p=18F4520
#include <P18F4520.INC>
CONFIG OSC = XT
CONFIG WDT = OFF
CONFIG LVP = OFF
CBLOCK 0x000
    DELAY_H
    DELAY_L
    DELAY_U
    input
endc

ORG 0x0000
goto Main
ORG 0x0800
    BTFSC   INTCON,INT0IF
    call    INT0_ISR
    BTFSC   INTCON3,INT1IF
    call    INT1_ISR
    RETFIE

ORG 0x0100
Main
    movlw   0x0F
    movwf   ADCON1
    clrf    TRISD
    clrf    PORTD
    setf    TRISB

    BCF     INTCON,INT0IF
    BSF     INTCON,INT0IE
    BCF     INTCON2,INTEDG0
    BCF     INTCON3,INT1IF
    BSF     INTCON3,INT1IE
    BCF     INTCON2,INTEDG1
    BSF     INTCON,GIE

    movlw   0x00
    movwf   input
    call    bcd_7seg
    movwf   PORTD

count   equ 0x25
    movlw   0x0A
    movwf   count
sec     
    incf    input, F
    call    bcd_7seg
    movwf   PORTD
    call    Delay
    decf    count, F
    bnz     sec
    goto    count


bcd_table:
db 0x3F, 0x06, 0x5B, 0x4F, 0x66, 0x6D, 0x7D, 0x07, 0x7F, 0x6F, 0x3F
bcd_7seg:
    movlw   low bcd_table
    movwf   TBLPTRL
    movlw   high bcd_table
    movwf   TBLPTRH
    movlw   upper bcd_table
    movwf   TBLPTRU
    movf    input, W
    addwf   TBLPTRL, F
    movlw   0
    addwfc  TBLPTRH
    addwfc  TBLPTRU
    TBLRD*
    movf    TABLAT, W
    RETURN


Delay: 
    MOVLW   d'10'
    MOVWF   DELAY_U
LOP1_0:
    MOVLW   0x80
    MOVWF   DELAY_H
LOP1_1:
    MOVLW   0xFF
    MOVWF   DELAY_L
LOP1_2:
    DECF    DELAY_L, F
    BNZ LOP1_2
    DECF    DELAY_H, F
    BNZ LOP1_1 
    DECF    DELAY_U, F
    BNZ LOP1_0
    return

INT0_ISR : ? 


INT1_ISR : ?


delay:      
    MOVLW   D'100'
    MOVWF   1
back
    MOVLW   D'0'
    MOVWF   2
here
    NOP
    NOP
    NOP
    NOP
    NOP
    NOP
    decf    2, F
    BNZ     here
    decf    1, F
    BNZ     back
    return

end
```

Even though I didn't put any instructions in INT0_ISR and INT1_ISR, both button1 and button changes the number on LED to 1. What instructions should I put in INT0_ISR and INT1_ISR to give out the correct result? Thank you for your help!

Comment: The line `count   equ 0x25` assigns the value 0x25 to the label 'count'. I don't think that was your intent.